# Word for giving something color?

Tags: word-request

Is there any word in the English language that expressly means to "color something in"? A word like colorize, but for instances where the means used to "color in" an image doesn't involve a computer?

> I _____ed this old photo. It was formerly portrayed in monochrome, but now it is adorned in every color on the spectrum.

> I intend to _____ this coloring book sometime today.

Comment: You use "color in" in your question, which is a perfectly good *two*-word expression for this.

Comment: @TimPederick: That should be an answer, I think; comments aren't really for answering.

Comment: While I appreciate the speedy accept, [you may want to wait a while longer to allow others to vote, other answers, and so forth](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Comment: @NathanTuggy: I *was* going to write an answer, but then (a) I realised that suggesting "color in" wasn't *really* an answer, more a tangential comment of "hey, there's nothing wrong with the **two** words you're already using", and (b) you beat me to the punch with "color", which was the most "answer"-like (one-word) part of my answer.

Comment: @TimPederick: Honestly, I kind of wish I'd put in the phrasal verb part; it's enough different I think it stands alone, and [there's definitely nothing wrong with an answer that tells someone that the word they'd rejected is actually fine](//ell.stackexchange.com/questions/104320/does-unbuild-in-unbuild-your-legos-before-putting-them-back-into-the-box-sou/104324#104324).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "color" itself for this, and that's customary especially for talking about coloring books. For photos, it's more common to say that you "tint" them.

Answer (score 2):

### This old photo

For any process of applying color to a black-and-white photo or film, as in your first example, you could use the word "colorize" even if the process was not done by a computer.

> I **colorized** this old photo.

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/colorize) defines "colorize" as "to cause to appear in color; enhance with color, especially by computer"; "especially" implies that it is possible to colorize without a computer. Also, the Wikipedia article on [film colorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_colorization) has sections on both "hand colorization" and "digital colorization".

If you are dead-set on avoiding the word "colorize", then take [Nathan Tuggy](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/10820/nathan-tuggy)'s advice and use the word "tint".

### This coloring book

In your second example, you could use either "color" [["to give color to; to change the color of (as by dyeing, staining, or painting)"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/color)] or, as [Tim Pederick](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/6120/tim-pederick) suggested, "color in" [["to add color to (a shape or picture) by using markers, crayons, colored pencils, etc."](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/color%20in)]. The latter is more specific to coloring books, but both sound natural to my ear.

> I intend to **color** this coloring book sometime today.
>
> I intend to **color in** this coloring book sometime today.